# Does necessitarianism make the concept of law of nature vacuous?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, necessity, laws-of-nature

I am someone who believes that everything is necessary, that only the actual is possible. However, I came across a somewhat disturbing implication of my view. I believe my view entails that every true statement about the physical world, is a law of nature. For example, the statement "There is a book on my desk" would be a law of nature, since it couldn't be otherwise, according to my view. I find this untenable. Anyway, my question is, has any necessitarian philosopher found a way to define laws of nature so as to rescue our intuition that only some true statements about the physical world are laws of nature? Or does necessitarian, in fact, make the concept of law of nature vacuous?

Comment: If one believes that only the actual is possible and that everything is necessary, one doesn't really have the concepts of possibility or necessity in mind, ultimately (one cannot distinguish them from each other or from mere actuality). But at any rate, one might go on to identify laws of nature with *general* facts; their character as "laws" is that they determine particulars to be a certain way, e.g. a specific book's being on a specific desk is a specific instance of a "law" about when books are on whichever desks.

Comment: It is fairly easy to distinguish true statements even about a deterministic physical world  from laws of nature. For one, laws are expressed by quantified general predicates with no named objects in them. For refinements of this generality approach see [SEP, What is it to be a Law?](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/#BasQueWhaItLaw)

Comment: Natural law is a legal concept ; laws of nature is a scientific one governed by the philosophy of science

Comment: I think you are confusing laws of nature, i.e. regularities in the behavior of physical things and anecdotic happenstances. "Massive objects attract each others" is a law of Nature, "Earth orbits the Sun", although it is the direct result of said law and was necessary in your view, is merely a side effect. just like the presence of the book on your desk.

Comment: In your classical necessitarian deterministic view initial conditions of the universe and laws of nature are all there is sufficiently, your vacuous ideal may be satisfactorily fully realizable if this initial condition is some fine tuned law of nature by some universal prior of causal events structure assuming the fundamental spacetime is discrete…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I came across a somewhat disturbing implication of my view. I believe my view entails that every true statement about the physical world, is a law of nature. For example, the statement "There is a book on my desk" would be a law of nature, since it couldn't be otherwise, according to my view.

**That shouldn't come as a disturbing implication. It is directly a result of the relationship between language and observation.** Laws of Nature are linguistic artifacts, that roughly speaking reflect the bias of the experiences of the observer, an idea that roughly comes from the notion of the **theory-ladeness of scientific theory itself**. The Laws of Nature do not dictate how the universe works, but describe the beliefs of the observer of the universe. It is a category mistake, particularly one of the [map-territory relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation) to claim otherwise.

**Modern philosophy of science, what Zammito recounts in his history on [post-postivist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositivism) thinking, is amenable to anti-realism in its stance towards any so-called "Laws of Nature"**. Given the influence of Quine, Lakatos, Sellars, and others, thinkers such as van Fraassen are not only willing to question the reality of "Laws of Nature", but bring to bear the question of ontological ambiguity to the door-step of putative scientific ontological primitives themselves.

Thus, the vacuity of the phrase "Laws of Nature" is not just possible, it is practically guaranteed because the things to which said "Laws" refer are themselves epistemologically uncertain. **What good is making claims about the physical experience of 'light' when light itself seem to be mysteriously both a wave and a particle determined only by the apparatus and operational procedure designed to define it?** Here again, we see where the fact-value distinction fails, when our facts are determined by our values. **And your necessitarian values largely allow you to overdetermine the Laws.**